# Redux saga function is not being called

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I tried to use redux-saga in my React project, but redux-saga function is not being called. `toggleLoginModal` action in `access.actions.js` is called, but `toggleLoginModal` in `access.sagas.js` is not called.

**Header.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import accessActions from 'actions/access.actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './Header.scss';

const { toggleLoginModal, toggleRegisterModal } = accessActions;

class Header extends Component {
  handleLoginClick = () => {
    toggleLoginModal(true);
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="navbar-right">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-link" onClick={this.handleLoginClick}>Log in</button>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(null, { toggleLoginModal, toggleRegisterModal })(Header));
```

**access.action.js**

```
const actions = {
  TOGGLE_LOGIN_MODAL: 'TOGGLE_LOGIN_MODAL',
  TOGGLE_LOGIN_MODAL_RETURN: 'TOGGLE_LOGIN_MODAL_RETURN',
  toggleLoginModal: newState => ({
    type: actions.TOGGLE_LOGIN_MODAL,
    state: newState,
  }),
  toggleLoginModalReturn: (newState) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({
        type: actions.TOGGLE_LOGIN_MODAL_RETURN,
        newState,
      });
    };
  },
};
export default actions;
```

**access.sagas.js**

```
import { all, takeEvery, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import actions from 'actions/access.actions';

export function* toggleLoginModal({ state }) {
  yield put(actions.toggleLoginModalReturn(state));
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(actions.TOGGLE_LOGIN_MODAL, toggleLoginModal),
  ]);
}
```

**access.reducers.js**

```
export function toggleModals(state = { login: false, register: false }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_LOGIN_MODAL_RETURN':
      return { login: action.newState };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**reducers.js**

```
import { toggleModals } from 'state/access.reducers.js';

export default {
  toggleModals,
};
```

**sagas.js**

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import accessSagas from 'sagas/access.sagas';

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([accessSagas()]);
}
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { ConnectedRouter, routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly';

import App from 'App';
import reducers from 'reducers';
import sagas from 'sagas';

const history = createHistory();
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    router: routerReducer,
  }),
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(
    routerMiddleware(history),
    sagaMiddleware,
  )),
);

sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-loadable": "^5.4.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "react-tippy": "^1.2.2",
    "react-toastify": "^4.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems.

First you need to use `toggleLoginModal` from props - as it is wrapped in `dispatch` thanks to `connect`. To cite https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

> [mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or
>   Function): If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed
>   to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names,
>   but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may
>   be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.

So in Header.jsx use:

```
handleLoginClick = () => {
    this.props.toggleLoginModal(true);
};
```

Second problem is that you use `toggleLoginModalReturn` as a thunk without having thunk middleware. Add `redux-thunk` to your list of middlewares.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to follow [this](https://github.com/halumz/react-saga-todo) project, where is similar [sagas.js](https://github.com/halumz/react-saga-todo/blob/master/src/redux/sagas.js) code. If I try your example, I get `uncaught at rootSaga at rootSaga 
 Error: fork: argument [object Generator] is not a function` error

Comment: Are you sure you used `fork(accessSagas)` and not `fork(accessSagas())` ? `[object Generator]` is what you get once you call the saga.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry my bad. I tried it out, but nothing changed, `toggleLoginModal` in `access.sagas.js` is not called. However, action `toggleLoginModal` is called.

Comment: Right, so I looked a bit closer at your code and found the actual cause of your problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. How is it possible that in that example project actions are not triggered from `props` ? For example [showMore](https://github.com/halumz/react-saga-todo/blob/master/src/components/todos.js) function here.

Comment: They are, see line 59. They are using object destructuring to get the showMore action out of props.

Answer (score 1):

Just leaving this here because it might help someone. I came across an issue when configuring sagas for a project where the saga would not trigger even though everything was configured and set up just right. The console didn't throw any errors either. But the actual problem was that when defining the default values for the state, where I was supposed to give default values for objects, I just passed null instead of constructing whole objects with the properties (lazy me).

So that actually causes errors where if you are trying to access properties from those objects but you pass the initial value as null, you'll be trying to access properties from null - which would mess up the project. And in some cases, it throws errors and some cases it doesn't. So this was the reason that the saga wasn't working correctly either.

Answer (score 0):

Just dropping this in case someone finds it useful.
I was using `connect` from `react-redux` to bind `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

For some reason when I was using `mapDispatchToProps` as a function, the actions dispatched was never able to reach the saga listener. All I had to do was *shift the variable from the function to a simple object instead*.

FROM

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onChange: (settings) => saveUserSettings(settings),
  fetchDataOnMount: getUserSettings,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Settings);
```

TO :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  userSettings: selectUserSettings(state),
  userSettingsStatus: selectUserSettingsStatus(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  onChange: (settings) => saveUserSettings(settings),
  fetchDataOnMount: getUserSettings,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Settings);
```

while my action file exporting:

```
export const getUserSettings = () => ({type: actions.FETCH_USER_SETTINGS});

export const saveUserSettings = (settings) => ({type: actions.SAVE_USER_SETTINGS, settings});
```

I realized there was no necessity for having a function defined for mapDispatchToProps as I was not using the dispatch parameter on the function. Moreover, each field of my returning object was utilizing the action creators directly and in this case, we can [Object Shorthand form](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#object-shorthand-form) where:

> React-Redux binds the dispatch of your store to each of the action
> creators using bindActionCreators.

[Read more](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) about defining `mapDispatchToProps` as an object.